# How can I make Japanese characters appear correctly in a JTextField?

Tags: java, internationalization, character-encoding

I have copied [http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/メインページ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8) url and pasted that url into a `JTextField` but it shows some squares( [][]...[].) instead of those chars "メインページ". How can I solve this problem so that the url is shown correctly?

Like this, see when I copy url (of any language) into this message box it is showing as it is, not as squares....

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: what OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the font installed on the computer that your app is running on.  If this is an English version of windows (or any other non-Japanese version, i suppose), you may need to download and install the font.  you can get [MS Mincho](http://www.themeworld.com/cgi-bin/redir.pl/fonts/msmincho.zip) here.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Java installer only installs English fonts (and no asian fonts) if it thinks this computer only speaks English.

Consider reinstalling the default JRE with a custom install where you install all fonts.